# Python Value Output Changing when pushed to Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, web-scraping, gspread, instaloader

I've used Instaloader to collect profile data and push to a Google Sheet.  In terminal, the output is correct.

When the info loads into the spreadsheet - the numbers are inaccurate.

I've tried switching the type of followee.followees (integer, string, float), but none have worked.

Has anyone found a solution for this? Confused what else I could try.  My code is below:

```
import gspread
import instaloader
loader = instaloader.Instaloader()

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1cD8mX8tR2iSQgSmpk6QxBVVHYVV8VxGs2uhtA8iBSpQ')
worksheet = sh.sheet1

loader.login(username, password)

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(loader.context, "nba")

followees = profile.get_followees()

for followee in profile.get_followees():
    print('{} has {} followees'.format(followee.username, followee.followers))

    AddValue = [followee.username, int(followee.followees)]
    worksheet.append_row(AddValue)
```

This is my terminal result:

[image: VS Output]

Whereas this is the result that is pushed to Google Sheets (from the same code):

[image: Spreadsheet Result]

As you can see, the numbers are drastically different.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your desired output and what you are currently getting?

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 just updated my question to include results

Answer (score 0):

Script has small typo -

```
 AddValue = [followee.username, int(followee.followers)]
```

should be

`AddValue = [followee.username, int(followee.followees`)]

Nothing to do with type, I was just calling the wrong value (followers vs. followees)

Comment: Both lines look the same. Could you please clarify what the typo is?